# How to use JWT authentication for WebMethods API Gateway

Tags: jwt, api-gateway, webmethods

I tried to enable JWT authentication on WebMethods API Gateway but all my JWT tokens are invalid.

I can successfully generated JWT tokens on my API Gateway server with this url :
http://API_GATEWAY_SERVER:API_GATEWAY_SERVER_PORT/rest/pub/apigateway/jwt/getJsonWebToken

But when I want to use it in an API endpoint, I have the 401 unauthorized error code
(api endpoint sample : http://webmethods_integration_server:5555/rad/MY_API:MY_API_rad/webmethods_flow_service_to_call)

Does anybody know how to configure JWT authentication in WebMethods API Gateway ?